# Crash when counting NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a NSDictionary that contains multiple keys with the same name. Here is the structure:

```
Dictionary {

    "Text" => "Blah",
    "Text" => "Blah 2",
    "Text" => "Blah 3"

}
```

So there are three keys with the same name `Text`. I put the values of `Text` into a `NSMutableArray` using:

```
NSDictionary *notes = [d objectForKey:@"notes"]; //dictionary above
NSMutableArray *notesA = [notes valueForKey:@"Text"];
NSLog(@"%i", notesA.count);
```

However, when I try to get the number of items in the array, it crashes with the following error:

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x856c110
```

Any idea why this is happening? I am able to output the values of the `NSMutableArray` and see them, but can't count them.

---

Here is the XML file:

```
<tickets>
 <text>Blah</text>
 <text>Blah 2</text>
 <text>Blah 3</text>
</tickets>
```

Notes dictionary output:

```
(
        {
        text = "Blah";
    },
        {
        text = "Blah 1";
    },
        {
        text = "Blah 2";
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding NSStrings as objects, not a NSArray.

```
NSDictionary *notes = [NSDictionray dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjetcs:@"Blah",@"Blah 2", @"Blah3"],@"Text",nil];

NSMutableArray *notesA = [notes objectForKey:@"Text"];
NSLog(@"%i", [notesA count]);
```

As we are using a NSMutableArray, this would be valid too:

```
NSDictionary *notes = [NSDictionray dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSMutableArray array],@"Text",nil];

NSMutableArray *notesA = [notes objectForKey:@"Text"];
[notesA addObject:@"Blah"];
[notesA addObject:@"Blah 2"];
[notesA addObject:@"Blah 3"];
NSLog(@"%i", [notesA count]);
```

---

BTW:

```
Dictionary {

    "Text" => "Blah",
    "Text" => "Blah 2",
    "Text" => "Blah 3"

}
```

This is not a valid NSDictionary structure, as keys have to be unique.

What you want is:

```
Dictionary {
    "Text" => ["Blah", "Blah 2","Blah 3"]    
}
```

If you set several objetcs for the same key, the older object will be replaced by the newer.

---

When the parser parses the tickets tag, it should create a array which it uses to add the single texts.

---

```
(
        {
        text = "Blah";
    },
        {
        text = "Blah 1";
    },
        {
        text = "Blah 2";
    }
)
```

Your notes object isnt a dictionary. it is an array with 3 dictionaries in it. each has an key text and some blah value.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: first you should tell us, how you create the dictionary, as you see, I am working on an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the NSDictionary from an XML file I am parsing. The XML file has multiple tags with the same name (I'll add a sample to my question). When I use `objectForKey`, it crashes.

Comment: I added the `notes` dictionary to the question. Everything is there, and as I said, I can put all of the objects in the array using what I previously had, but it won't count.

Comment: see my edit. you must handle in the parser, that tickets can have n text tags.

Comment: the structure u have there is an array with 3 dictionaries. This is not what you want.